# Как изменить размер двухмерного QVector при помощи метода resize()?

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Как изменить размер двухмерного QVector ? Я пробовал следующий код, выходит ошибка, при том, что в методе resize я указываю новый размер.

```
int m = 24;
int n = 9;
QVector <QVector <QString> > _preset_table(m, QVector<QString>(n, ""));
.
.
.
n = 30;
_preset_table.resize(m*n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        _preset_table[j][i] = "Текст";
    };
};
```

Т.е. программа работает только для n <= 9;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строкой `_preset_table.resize(m*n);` Вы увеличиваете размер по первой размерности, при чем сильно больше, чем Вам нужно, а вот другие даже не трогает

Вам нужен цикл

```
_preset_table.resize(m);
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  _preset_table[i].resize(n);
}
```

Хотя я бы использовал `push_back`/`append`.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал push_back/append, - не изменяется размер, тоже вылетает ошибка почему-то...

Comment: push_back нужно правильно использовать. просто так в лоб нельзя. Не забывайте, у Вас две размерности и с каждой нужно работать отдельно.

Comment: Сработал вариант for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {_preset_table[i].resize(n);}. Спасибо!

Comment: @KoVadim А разве здесь: `i < n;` не должно быть `i < m;`?

Comment: да, да. исправил